# How to trigger Unselected command of imap via JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

We need to trigger unselected command in IMAP via Javamail. Is there anyone can tell?

momoren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the folder is open READ_WRITE:

```
 folder.close(false);
```